# Updating run_daily time in Python Telegram Bot through users input

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a problem, when user of the bot wants to update a time of a **run_daily**.

Example of the code.

```
def send_message_to_the_user(context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID,text="Example of the message")

def main():
    updater = Updater(API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    job = updater.job_queue
    job.run_daily(send_message_to_the_user(), time=ALARM)

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, set_timer))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


main()
```

I've tried going with a messy way of doing it with a global variable. **MessageHandler** would detect **set_timer** in the message and would update **global ALARM** variable that **run_daily** is using, but when I would run the code/bot **run_daily** would only run at the time that was set before I ran the code/bot. If user would try to update the **ALARM** variable with **set_timer** command it would update the **ALARM** but **run_daily** would just use the time that was set before bot was started.

Is there a way I can dynamically update "**time=**" inside **run_daily**?

Or somehow restart **run_daily** after user updates his/her time.

run_daily docs -- https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_daily

Comment: Can you include the code (or documentation reference if 3rd party) for run_daily?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I've edited it and included docs to run_daily, which is apart of Python-Telegram-Bot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just schedule a new job, then.

- Pass a unique `name` to `run_daily`
- Use that name and [`JobQueue.get_jobs_by_name`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.get_jobs_by_name) to get the job
- use [`Job.schedule_removal`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.job.html#telegram.ext.Job.schedule_removal) to delete the job
- use `JobQueue.run_daily` to schedule a new job.

Also have a look at the [`timerbot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/v13.x/examples#timerbotpy) example, which does something similar.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintiner of `python-telegram-bot`.